# React ZMQ, Router to Dealer, not working. ZMQ 4.0.5

Tags: php, zeromq, reactphp

I want to do an asynchronous router to dealer messaging with React but it isn't working. The code in http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:rtdealer is working, but I can't identify what I'm doing different. I'm using libzmq 4.0.5

Here is my code:

```
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);

$worker = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_DEALER);
$worker->setSockOpt(\ZMQ::SOCKOPT_IDENTITY, 'A');
$worker->connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5556');
$worker->send('END');

$worker->on('error', function ($e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
});

$worker->on('messages', function($msg) use ($worker) {
    echo 'Dealer messages'. PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($msg);
});

$worker->on('message', function($msg) use ($worker) {
    echo 'Dealer message'. PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($msg);
});

$router = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_ROUTER);
$router->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5556');

$i = 0;
$loop->addPeriodicTimer(1, function (React\EventLoop\Timer\Timer $timer) use (&$i, $router) {
    echo 'Time to send!'. PHP_EOL;
    $i++;
    $router->send('A', \ZMQ::MODE_SNDMORE);
    $router->send('END');
});

$router->on('messages', function($msg) use ($router) {
    echo 'Router messages'. PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($msg);
});

$router->on('message', function($msg) {
    echo 'Router message'. PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($msg);
});

$loop->run();
```

The problem is that only the dealer sends the first message "END". After that, router tries to send messages but dealer does not receive them.

Also, this function seems to be only called once:

```
// \React\ZMQ\SocketWrapper
public function handleReadEvent()
{
    $messages = $this->socket->recvmulti(ZMQ::MODE_NOBLOCK);
    echo 'Receiving...';    // Added
    var_dump($messages);    // Added

    if ($messages !== false) {
        if (count($messages) === 1) {
            $this->emit('message', array($messages[0]));
        }

        $this->emit('messages', array($messages));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Receiving...array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "END"
}
Router messages
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "END"
}
Time to send!
Time to send!
Time to send!
Time to send!
Time to send!
...
```

**Edit:**

Changed the code to bind the router before the dealer connects to it, the problem is still happening:

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);

$router = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_ROUTER);
$router->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5556');

$loop->addPeriodicTimer(10, function (React\EventLoop\Timer\Timer $timer) use ($router) {
    echo 'Router sending messages with an interval of 10 seconds'. PHP_EOL;
    $router->send('A', \ZMQ::MODE_SNDMORE);
    $router->send('END');
});

$router->on('messages', function($msg) use ($router) {
    echo 'Router messages'. PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($msg);
});

$router->on('message', function($msg) {
    echo 'Router message'. PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($msg);
});

$worker = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_DEALER);

$loop->addPeriodicTimer(5, function (React\EventLoop\Timer\Timer $timer) use ($worker) {
    echo 'After 5 seconds from router binding, connect the dealer and send something'. PHP_EOL;
    $worker->setSockOpt(\ZMQ::SOCKOPT_IDENTITY, 'A');
    $worker->connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5556');
    $worker->send('END');
    $timer->getLoop()->cancelTimer($timer);     // Cancel the timer after connecting
});

$worker->on('error', function ($e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
});

$worker->on('messages', function($msg) use ($worker) {
    echo 'Dealer messages'. PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($msg);
});

$worker->on('message', function($msg) use ($worker) {
    echo 'Dealer message'. PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($msg);
});

$loop->run();
```

This is the terminal output:

```
After 5 seconds from router binding, connect the dealer and send something
Receiving...array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "END"
}
Router messages
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "END"
}
Router sending messages with an interval of 10 seconds
Router sending messages with an interval of 10 seconds
Router sending messages with an interval of 10 seconds
Router sending messages with an interval of 10 seconds
Router sending messages with an interval of 10 seconds
Router sending messages with an interval of 10 seconds
Router sending messages with an interval of 10 seconds
Router sending messages with an interval of 10 seconds
```

Comment: I'm not certain because I don't use php, but 0MQ requires separate threads for separate sockets. In the sample link you provided that is achieved by `worker_a` & `worker_b` being forked. I'd guess that's your problem.

Comment: @Amit - it doesn't require separate threads for separate sockets. You can multiplex ZMQ sockets in the same process or thread. On topic - what is the version of libzmq you're using?

Comment: Since there are many issues with zmq between versions when it comes to binding or connecting order, I suggest that you bind first (as in the example provided), sleep for a second so the threads achieve what they need to and then connect the dealer and try again. If the error persists, then you can rule out that it's the order of bind/connect and we can try to take a look at something else.

Comment: @N.B. I've updated the title of the question with de ZMQ version (4.0.5). I've also changed my code so the dealer connects after 5 seconds from binding the router. The problem still persists.

Comment: For the sake of your example, try using `inproc` instead of TCP... I doubt it *should* make a difference, but it's the "best" choice when you're sockets are in the same process and that amounts to eliminating potential problem spots in this case.  Not having used PHP/React, are you certain your namespacing is correct?

Comment: @Jason I've tried changing to ```inproc``` but the same problem occurs. Yeah, my namespacing is correct and I've tried the synchronous basic REQ-REP pattern and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally solved the problem. Helped by @Jason's comment *Not having used PHP/React, are you certain your namespacing is correct?* , I looked at the `send`method called. This method looks like this:

```
// \React\ZMQ\SocketWrapper

public function send($message)
{
    echo 'Inside send, sending message'. PHP_EOL; //This line was added by myself
    $this->buffer->send($message);
}
```

Then, I thought: well, if I'm calling this method this way:

```
$router->send('A', \ZMQ::MODE_SNDMORE);
```

The second argument is never passed.

Then, I saw that the `sendmulti`method was not implemented in the `SocketWrapper`and the `__call`method was implemented in this `SocketWrapper` class tho call directly the method implemented in the ZMQ api for PHP, so I tried to call `sendmulti`wrapping this two parameters in an array. It worked, so I tried to call the first `send`method passing the same array and I don't know why but it worked too, so the trick was calling:

```
$router->send(array('A', \ZMQ::MODE_SNDMORE));
$router->send(array('END'));
```

Instead of:

```
$router->send('A', \ZMQ::MODE_SNDMORE);
$router->send('END');
```

Also, be careful with the ZMQ PHP API located in the GitHub repository, it's wrong. PhpStorm downloaded somehow another ZMQ PHP API located somewhere that seems to be correct, the `sendmulti`method prototype looks like this in this API:

```
public function sendmulti(array $message, $mode = 0)
```

Surprisingly, the following calls to this method seem to give the same results:

```
$router->send(array('A', \ZMQ::MODE_SNDMORE));
$router->send(array('A'), \ZMQ::MODE_SNDMORE);
```

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out, and that my suggestion, though wrong, helped get your eyes on the right spot :)